# Debian dpkg broken after apt-get upgrade

Tags: debian, dpkg

I have been running Debian Wheezy for a long time. Today I ran a `dpkg upgrade`, which has somehow broken things badly. The upgrade aborted, and now `apt-get` and `dpkg` are not running.

```
# dpkg
dpkg: error while loading shared libraries: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can download the .deb files that contain the missing files, but I cannot install them without working tools. How do I get out of this catch 22?

Comment: Boot from a live cd and install the deb. I think you can pass a chroot argument to `dpkg`.

Comment: can you locate libselinux.so.1 on your system. you can also check `ldd /usr/bin/dpkg` for missing dependencies on `dpkg`.

Comment: Actually, `ldd` has missing dependencies :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Library files in the standard directories must be registered in a cache for performance. If the upgrade aborted at the wrong time, it's possible that you have library files that are present in the filesystem but not in the cache. Run [`ldconfig`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) as root to update the cache.

To help troubleshoot dynamic library problems, it can help to have some statically linked utility suites: [busybox-static](http://packages.debian.org/busybox-static), [sash](http://packages.debian.org/sash), [zsh-static](http://packages.debian.org/zsh-static).

Comment: The busybox-static package turned out to be quite useful.

Comment: running ldbconfig fixed this issue for me thanks Gilles

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the contents of a `.deb` file using a combination of the `ar` and `tar` commands:

```
mkdir /tmp/selinux
cd /tmp/selinux
ar p /path/to/libselinux.deb data.tar.gz | tar xz
```

This the contents of the package will be unpacked in a hierarchy rooted at your current directory, and you can move the required files to the appropriate place.
For libselinux this is likely to be just `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1` (directory name depending on your architecture).

Once you have that working again, you should probably use `dpkg -i` to reinstall the full package.

Comment: I managed to place back the file in that directory (using a different method, but this looks nice), but it's still giving me the same error. It seems to be looking in the wrong place... work in progress :)

Comment: It may help to run `ldconfig` after putting the library back in place.

Comment: You should also check that there's a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` which lists the directory where the library is located. On my system it's listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf`.

Comment: Or it may be that `ldconfig` is what got hosed in the first place.

Comment: @qqx That file was there with the proper directory. I hadn't tried ldconfig. I managed to get dpkg running again but while fixing some package conflicts things got broken even more badly. Now trying a rescue CD.